# Bash autocomplete doesn't escape SPACE and doesn't mark directories in Ubuntu 11.4

Tags: bash, autocomplete, escaping

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.4 and I'm having problems with Bash autocomplete

for example, if I want to cd to Calibre Library directory, when I type

```
cd Cal<TAB>
```

I get

```
cd Calibre Library CURSOR
```

the autocomplete just prints the file/directory name, without escaping the SPACE or any other non alphanumeric characters, and it doesn't mark directories, it is really annoying

I've looked through /etc/inputrc and even added

```
# append a '/' to show a dir is a dir
set mark-directories on
set mark-symlinked-directories on
```

but it doesn't help :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is due to a conflict between bash-completion 1.3 and acroread. See http://forums.adobe.com/thread/745833 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/716008 . A workaround is removing `/etc/bash_completion.d/acroread.sh`, then execute `. /etc/bash_completion`.

Comment: Thanks a million Zanetu.

I had to run 'sudo bash /etc/bash_completion'.

This was really a surprise for me that something like Acrobat Reader can stuff up autocomplete!