# bash completion isn't working like it used to -- not escaping spaces and oddities in filenames, etc

Tags: bash, ubuntu, bash-completion, debian-based

Okay, I just don't understand why this isn't working automatically.

When I'm working on my mac, spaces and other odd characters get escaped automatically when I do autocomplete in bash, but on my ubuntu box, they don't. Even worse, if I do escape the character, then try autocomplete, the escapes *disappear*. Why doesn't debian's bash complete know how to deal with spaces and other chars that need escaping out of the box??

Comment: did you change anything in your autocomplete?  what terminal are you using?  what does your bash look like?

Comment: Have you modified your .bash_profile or .bashrc file?

Comment: @Lipongo Yes, i've modified .profile and .bashrc. I've added some aliases, and such. I've also added some files to .bashrc.d. I have not, however, touched the part in .bashrc where it loads /etc/bash_completion. That is still:

if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi

Comment: @Mutmatt nothing has changed in the /etc/bash_completion file. I'm not sure what you mean by "what does your bash look like"

Comment: I.E. what does your bashrc or bash profile look like

Comment: Likely something you changed in your .bash_profile or .bashrc file is causing the issue.

Comment: Here are the unaltered .bashrc and .profile of a newly created user, and the problem still exists when doing bash complete in a shell when logged in under this user: https://gist.github.com/3809601

Comment: what happens when you run `locate completion`?

Comment: P.S. that bashrc works A.O.K. for me in my term

Comment: @Mutmatt i get a very very long list of entries: https://gist.github.com/3815702

Comment: @Mutmatt that same .bashrc and .profile also work on my debian 6 VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe answer to my question appears here:

[Bash autocomplete doesn't escape SPACE and doesn't mark directories in Ubuntu 11.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852389/bash-autocomplete-doesnt-escape-space-and-doesnt-mark-directories-in-ubuntu-11?rq=1)

Remove `/etc/bash_completion.d/acroread.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Debian isn't the same thing as Ubuntu. Also, bash completion isn't part of bash proper, it's a package. I suggest simply uninstalling and reinstalling the package. If you're curious or have customized changes to the bash stack, back up your files beforehand for comparison.